The attribute name.formatted is required
Currently i am building a react-native app and doing authentication with aws amplify. and have the email and name as required attribute and then when i try to sign up then it is giving me the error
LOG  Error signing up: [InvalidParameterException: Attributes did not conform to the schema: name.formatted: The attribute name.formatted is required]
I have searched it everywhere on internet and also docs on aws amplify but i am not able to find the solution so if anyone has the solution then please tell

The title and question content do not match. Please clarify if the issue is with Angular Material or AWS Amplify.

This sounds stupid to me but it's what helped me get past this error. When you create a new user pool you have to dictate which attributes are required. Apparently I forgot I made the name attribute required and this is the ridiculous error that was thrown. I also could not find anywhere in the UI where I could find which attributes were required. All I had to do was add this attribute and my create user call worked
  var attributes = new List<AttributeType>()
        {
            new()
            {
                Name = "custom:userid",
                Value = userId.ToString()
            },
            new()
            {
                Name = "custom:orgid",
                Value = orgId.ToString()
            },
            new()
            {
                Name = "custom:permissions",
                Value = "[1,2,3]"
            },
            new()
            {
                Name = "name",
                Value = req.FullName
            }
        };


Thank you for the answer , I will try and see if it works for me

did it work for you?

No this did not work for me
